# Flux of electric field through the sphere

Tags: electrostatics, vector-fields

I am reading [Feyman lectures](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_01.html#Ch1-S2-p1)

> For an arbitrary closed surface, the net outward flow—or flux—is the average outward normal component of the velocity, times the area of the surface:

As far as I understand the average outward normal component on the velocity on the sphere should be zero due to symmetry. If there is normal vector $\vec r$ $(1,0,0)$, then there is also $\vec r$$(-1,0,0)$ to make average zero. So flux is zero as well. Am I correct?

Comment: Feynman is talking about “an arbitrary closed surface”, not necessarily a sphere, and arbitrary *fluid* flow across it. There is *no symmetry* to make use of to argue anything here.

Comment: @G.Smith thank you. What about sphere, will it cancel if we have to work with sphere? I guess my mistake is that I assumed that the electric field is symmetric. I assumed that electric field at diametrically opposing points is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The net flux will not be zero. The **total** flux of an electric field $\vec E$ generated by a **positively** charged particle through a closed surface, $\mathcal{S}$ which contains the charge is given by

$$\int\int_\mathcal{S}\vec E\cdot d\vec S \tag{1}.$$

But note that we're taking the **dot** product here, which, assuming there are only flux lines pointing **out** of the surface will **always** return a positive (or zero) value. You are forgetting that the normal vector $\vec dS$ points **normal** to the surface, whichever point on the surface you're looking at. If $d\vec S$ pointed in a fixed direction at all points on the surface $\mathcal{S}$ you would be right and the net flux would cancel to zero, but it doesn't. As in this image:

[image: Normal Vector from Wikipedia]

Comment: Good answer propably better than my answer.

Comment: Hey why is your answer at the top and mine at the bottom? :( Broken stackexchange mechanics.